# How to take an array of n integers delimited by white spaces and store them in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = sc.nextLine();
   String[] split = input.split("\\s+");
   int[] arr = new int[split.length];
   int i=0;
   for (String string : split) 
     arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Explain this code, how it is taking an array of n `integers`,
         delimited by  white spaces and store them in an `array`.

Comment: It looks like a programming class assignment, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` will have the string that you enter through the prompt. When `input.split("\\s+");` is executed, it splits the string with white spaces and store it as string arrays.

For example, if you entered 1 3 5 7, then the split will store four string arrays containing 1,3,5,7 in each of them.

Next, an `int` array is created with the size of the above split String array. Now loop through the string array, parse the string as Integer (using `Integer.parseInt()`) and convert the string to Integer.

`\\s+` is the regular expression to match all possible white spaces like space,tab, multiple spaces/tabs.

Hope that explains.